# HTML repopulate input text or textarea with original text

Tags: php, html, textarea

I want to have a text-field (input type="text") or text-area in html that takes users input. After "submit" clicked, PHP returns results. I want to repopulate the text-field or text-area with original user input. However my code only works with text-field, but not text-area:

This works:

```
    <INPUT TYPE = "text" NAME = "seqbox" SIZE = 50 PLACEHOLDER = "Enter sequence here" VALUE = "<?php if(isset($_GET['seqbox'])) {echo $_GET['seqbox'];} ?>">
```

This does not work:

```
    <TEXTAREA NAME = "seqbox" COLS=100 ROWS=20 PLACEHOLDER = "Enter sequence here" VALUE = "<?php if(isset($_GET['seqbox'])) {echo $_GET['seqbox'];} ?>"></TEXTAREA>
```

Any idea why? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Textarea doesn't have a value property.  You need to set it in between the element like this:

```
<TEXTAREA NAME = "seqbox" COLS=100 ROWS=20 PLACEHOLDER = "Enter sequence here">
<?php if(isset($_GET['seqbox'])) {echo $_GET['seqbox'];} ?>
</TEXTAREA>
```

Answer (score 0):

Textareas don't take a `value` attribute.

```
<TEXTAREA NAME = "seqbox" COLS=100 ROWS=20 PLACEHOLDER = "Enter sequence here"><?php if(isset($_GET['seqbox'])) {echo $_GET['seqbox'];} ?></TEXTAREA>
```

A note: you should run `$_GET['seqbox']` through `htmlspecialchars` or malicious users will be able to inject things like JavaScript into your page through a specially crafted URL (an [XSS vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)).